# Counting Comparisons When The Pivot Is Not The First Element

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have tried to implement the Quicksort algorithm, but different pivots don't seem to work. 
When the pivot element is not the first element, it always ends in a recursive loop resulting in a crash where the variable i falls off of the array and it calls itself again with the full array and nothing changes. I think the error is the comparison comparing toSort[j] with the pivot value, or the first element after being swapped with the other element.

```
public static void quickSort(int[] toSort, int l, int r){
    if(r - l <= 1)return;
    counter += r - l - 1;
    int p = choosePivot(l, r);
    int pivot = toSort[p];
    int oldP = toSort[p];
    toSort[p] = toSort[l];
    toSort[l] = oldP;

    int i = l + 1;
    for(int j = l + 1; j < r; j++){
        if(toSort[j] < pivot){
            int swap = toSort[j];
            toSort[j] = toSort[i];
            toSort[i] = swap;
            i++;
        }
    }


    oldP = toSort[i - 1];
    toSort[i - 1] = toSort[l];
    toSort[l] = oldP;

    quickSort(toSort, l, i);
    quickSort(toSort, i, r);
}

public static int choosePivot(int m, int n){
    return n - 1;
    //return m;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the recursive call to `quickSort()` is not converging. A slight change in the last two lines will work like magic.

```
public static void quickSort(int[] toSort, int l, int r){
    if(r - l <= 1)return;
    counter += r - l - 1;
    int p = choosePivot(l, r);
    int pivot = toSort[p];
    int oldP = toSort[p];
    toSort[p] = toSort[l];
    toSort[l] = oldP;

    int i = l + 1;
    for(int j = l + 1; j < r; j++){
        if(toSort[j] < pivot){
            int swap = toSort[j];
            toSort[j] = toSort[i];
            toSort[i] = swap;
            i++;
        }
    }


    oldP = toSort[i - 1];
    toSort[i - 1] = toSort[l];
    toSort[l] = oldP;

    quickSort(toSort, l, i-1);
    quickSort(toSort, i, r);
}

public static int choosePivot(int m, int n){
    return n - 1;
    //return m;
}
```

You can check the [Ideone link](http://ideone.com/i12UQs) for updated code.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was a huge help!

Comment: @hello-world I thought you figured it out yourself lately.! Did above solution worked.?